# How to skip DMS validation on records which are deleted in target DB in DMS task "full load + ongoing replication"?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-dms

Continuously I am running DMS task with "full load + on-going replication" and enabled "validation" as well. Replication is working as expected but validation is getting failed when I delete old records from target database.

I was testing the below scenario (example). My DMS task is running continuously -

1. day 1 - '500' records replicated to target from source and DMS
   validation task is successful.
2. day 2 - before loading another '4000'
   new records into source database I deleted 'day 1' '500' records
   from target database. But validation is failed.

Here, observed that DMS task replicated only new '4000' records to target database, which is expected but it's trying to validate all the records (500 + 4000) then it is failed.
[image]

It looks like, DMS task is trying to validate deleted '500' records as well. When we enable CDC it should perform validation on on-going changes not already replicated records. Why it's performing entire validation every time? How to control this in DMS so that it can only validate on-going changes?